# How to monitor traffic usage on a Tor bridge on Linux?

Tags: relays, linux, bridge, ubuntu, traffic-analysis

I'll buy a small server and will install some Ubuntu distro on it, and among other things I'll install a Tor bridge that won't be an exit replay. I also will use it as a SOCKS proxy for a Firefox, I know this doesn't follow best anonimity practices.

Today my relay runs on Windows, as a Tor Expert bundle, executed by Vidalia. Vialia has a chart that shows last minutes traffic usage. Is it possible to config Tor to keep some sort of log about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Nyx](https://nyx.torproject.org/). That is probably how most relay operators on Linux get their bandwidth and connection information.